# Do I need a visa to enter Jordan to get to the USA?

Tags: visa, iraqi-citizens

My mother in law finally got her visa.  She probably will be taking Royal Jordanian airlines from EBL (Erbil, Iraq) to Amman, Jordan and then from Amman, Jordan to either Chicago, IL or if available Detroit, MI.

Does she need a visa to enter the country of Jordan?  She is a citizen of the country of Iraq.  She does not plan to stay in Jordan at all - at most she would be there for 5-10 hours in transit waiting on her flight.

Comment: You might get a quicker response at [Travel.SE]. Focus the question on the transit visa; if you talk too much about immigration it will get closed.   All I've been able to find is that Iraqis need to obtain visas prior to travel, but since she may not need to pass through immigration control she may not need a visa. Someone there probably knows the airport well enough to know whether that's the case.  Otherwise your best bet is to get in touch with the Jordanian consulate in Iraq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was no to this - my mother in law was simply in transit and was not staying more than 24 hours in the country of Jordan so a visa was not necessary.